# jquery - How to get mouse coordinates on window unload?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to get mouse coordinates when the window is unloaded? I've tried the following (in firefox) but it doesn't seem to let me pull much from `e` apart from `type` which returns `unload`.

```
$(window).unload(function(e) {
    var evt=window.event || e;
    alert(evt.pageX); // or screenX or clientX or whatever
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `unload` event, there isn't mouse coordinates included. (http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/wtp9X/)

[image]

But if you want a *hacky* solution, you can continuously track user's mouse position and use the last one in `unload`.

http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/gYEhF/

Comment: i kinda wanted it to compare it to the coordinates of the browsers X button, but i cant get the coordinates of that either haha, but yh for doing what i said in the question this has gota be the only solution

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).unload(function(e) {
    var evt = window.event || e;
    alert(evt.x + ',' + evt.y);//Also clientX.layerX,pageX,screenX, depending on what you want
});
```

Comment: yaa i get undefined for every single variation including 'x' and 'y' ^^